# Correct interpretation of Bayesian credible intervals

Tags: self-study, bayesian, credible-interval

I'm starting to learn about Bayesian statistics for my own personal education (this is not a homework question). Something puzzles me a bit about the interpretation of credible intervals.

From the few things I've read so far, it seems that their interpretation goes along the lines of (e.g. for a 95% credible interval):

> There is a 95% probability that the true (unknown) estimate would lie
> within the interval, given the evidence provided by the observed data.

(quotation [taken from here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30638956/))

This seems intuitive and straightforward, but shouldn't we add "***and given the prior we defined***" to the sentence above, to be perfectly accurate? (As the interval is affected by the prior, if I understood things correctly).

Or is there a reason for not mentioning priors?

In fact, I suspect that the presence of priors is implied with the word "evidence", but I'm not sure about it and would like some confirmation that I'm on the right track.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're just getting started with learning Bayesian statistics I would suggest going through [*Statistical Rethinking*](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDcUM9US4XdPz-KxHM4XHt7uUVGWWVSus). It is not mathematically rigorous, but focuses strongly on an intuitive understanding that can be refined into something mathematically rigorous later. Intervals are more a convenience for reporting to your audience at the end of an analysis; they're not the main show.

Comment: And also "given the assumptions about the data generating process we've made by using the model we specified."

Comment: "The data analyst would give 95% probability that the true parameter is between the bounds of the CrI, after analyzing the data, assuming the prior used represents what the analyst would give before seeing the data and that the model represents the probabilities the analyst would assign to the data when the parameters are known"

Comment: These are all good answers, and be sure to note that Bayes gives you the opportunity to turn this sideways and specify the intervals of interest, then getting the probability that the unknown parameter is in the user-controlled interval.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for these useful responses.